# please help me. ive been trying to solve this for hours

Tags: trigonometry

At 3:00 PM, a boat is 12.5 miles due west of a radar station and traveling at 11 mph in a direction that is 57.3 degrees south of an east-west line. At what time will the boat be closest to the radar station?

Comment: Check out the advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). A descriptive title would be a start.

Answer (score 2):

If i get the picture right you will have a triangle with sides 
$$A = 12.5 miles\\ B = 12.5 \cdot cos(57.3 deg) miles \\ C = 12.5 \cdot sin(57.3 deg) miles$$, because your traveling line $(B)$ should be 90 deg from the lighthouse when the distance is at minimum. Now when you know the length and the velocity you can calculate the traveling time and at what time you will reach this minimum.
Let the point $P$ be where $B$ and $C$ intersects, the point on the travelling line that has minimum distance to the lighthouse.

The length of $B$ is the distance you need to travel to reach the minimum distance. Travelling in 11mph yields
$$
t = \frac{12.5 cos(57.3 \ deg) \ miles}{11 \ mph}
$$
and from this, the time you get there will be 3:00PM + t

Comment: I think this is dangerous because the path you are traveling and the path from the point of least distance on that path to the lighthouse are different. Once of these will be the minimum distance and **the other** will be the distance to that point. Needs to be more clear.

Comment: I hope this is more clear now =)

Answer (score 2):

We **outline** the solution.  The work is left to you. This work, in the main, consists of drawing an appropriate diagram.

Put down a dot labelled $R$, to represent the radar station.

On a horizontal line through $R$, and to the *left* (west) of $R$ put down a dot labelled $B$ to indicate the $3$ PM position of the boat.  Note that the distance $RB$ is equal to $12.5$. Write that number somewhere close to the line segment $RB$.

Now draw a roughly diagonal line through $B$, going more or less in a south-east direction. That is the path taken by the boat after $3$ PM. Label some point on that line, well to the south of $B$, by some label like $F$.

Note that we were told that the boat is heading $57.3$ degrees south of an east-west line. That means that $\angle RBF=57.3^\circ$.

Draw a line through $R$ **perpendicular** to the line $BF$, and meeting line $BF$ at $N$. Then $N$ is the nearest point to $R$ on the path the boat is travelling,

Now it's almost over. You want the distance $BN$. This can be computed using the trigonometry of the right-angled triangle $RBN$.

Once you have found the distance $BN$, you can find how long it took to travel that distance, and answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I will give a few hints rather than solving directly.

1. Draw the situation!
2. The line of least distance from a point to a line is perpendicular to that line.
3. This gives you a right triangle.
4. You know the angle and length of the hypotenuse of that triangle.
5. Once you get your distance to your destination (along the correct path) use a simple velocity calculation to get the time needed to get there.

Comment: I actually labeled drawing the situation as the 0th rule. You should always do this.

Comment: Between 4 and 5 you should be figuring out which side of the triangle gives the distance traveled **along your path**... and this should be trivial since you drew a diagram.